# How do you run specs on ruby core?

Tags: ruby

I'm looking to make a change to the Ruby language itself. How would I run, for example, the [Hash#dig spec](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/spec/ruby/core/hash/dig_spec.rb) locally, much less the specs that (I assume) are written in C?

Comment: There's a README in the `spec` directory: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/trunk/spec#running-rubyspec

Comment: @Stefan that helps a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/trunk/spec#running-rubyspec), use this command if you want to run all specs:

```
make test-spec
```

To run a specific test, add its path to the command:

```
make test-spec MSPECOPT=spec/ruby/language/hash/dig_spec.rb
```